# Code Composer Studio doesn't compile any .asm files

Tags: assembly, code-composer

I downloaded CCS for one of my classes, and when given the professor's code it debugs with 23 errors but doesn't do that on anyone else's computer. I've tried everything to fix this and it has been confirmed that it has nothing to do with the code itself but something with my computer.

Below I added a screenshot of the error codes.
Has anyone seen this before? My professor, my TA, and I are all completely stumped.

[image: errors]